# My page is showing a diamond in the place of a accent

Tags: javascript, web, primefaces

I´m using primefaces

And trying to change the idiom of my page to portuguese.

But when i load the page, it shows a diamond with a question in the place of accent...

I´m using primefaces

And this code below is in JavaScript

```
PrimeFaces.locales['pt'] = {  
            closeText: 'Fechar',  
            prevText: 'Anterior',  
            nextText: 'Próximo',  
            currentText: 'Começo',  
            monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],  
            monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun', 'Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez'],  
            dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda','Terça','Quarta','Quinta','Sexta','Sábado'],  
            dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sáb'],  
            dayNamesMin: ['D','S','T','Q','Q','S','S'],  
            weekHeader: 'Semana',  
            firstDay: 1,  
            isRTL: false,  
            showMonthAfterYear: false,  
            yearSuffix: '',  
            timeOnlyTitle: 'Só Horas',  
            timeText: 'Tempo',  
            hourText: 'Hora',  
            minuteText: 'Minuto',  
            secondText: 'Segundo',  
            currentText: 'Data Atual',  
            ampm: false,  
            month: 'Mês',  
            week: 'Semana',  
            day: 'Dia',  
            allDayText : 'Todo Dia'  
        };
```

So what´s wrong?

Comment: Make sure you're using UTF8 everywhere.

Comment: You probably don't have enough UTF8.  Is every file saved as UTF8? Is the HTTP response specifying UTF8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your JavaScript file is saved with [UTF-8 with BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Byte_order_mark).  Also, your HTML file should use the same character set.  In HTML5, specify the encoding like this:

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

In Firefox, take a look at the [Page Info Window](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/page-info-window-view-technical-details-about-page?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Page+Info+window), Encoding line.